# How do I conditionally add an attribute directive to a child directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive, which I want to pass a show value into, which conditionally compiles an attribute directive on an inner directive.

eg,

```
<a-directive show-it="showIt"></a-directive>
```

If `showIt` were true, I want it to be replaced with

```
<a-directive show-it="showIt">
  <inner-directive value="[some expression]">
    <div>[some expression evaluated]</div>
  </inner-directive>
</a-directive>
```

where

- `[some expression]` needs to be interpreted (I'm guessing it needs to be `$compile`'d, but I'm not sure)
- `inner-directive` is in it's own template file, and has its own link function which sets some things up

Otherwise, if `showIt` were false, I want it to be replaced with

```
<a-directive show-it="showIt">
  <inner-directive></inner-directive>
</a-directive>
```

An example is shown here:

http://jsbin.com/uBIceCi/29/edit (the `$compile` I have creates an infinite loop if you uncomment it - tried it both in prelink and postlink functions).

<strike>http://jsbin.com/uBIceCi/7/edit (old example)</strike>

**Update**:

The practical application I have is that I want to conditionally add [typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) (which needs to be compiled) to my inner generated directive. ie, I have a <form> wrapper directive (`a-directive`) and an <input> directive (`inner-directive`), and I want to dynamically add the `typeahead` attribute directive in the input directive based on an attribute on the form directive.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you can my answer figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the desired template in the link function of your directive as follows

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showIt = false;
})
app.directive('aDirective', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var template1 = '<div>template1</div>';
            var template2 = '<div>template2</div>';
            if (scope.showIt) {
                element.append($compile(template1)(scope));
            } else {
                element.append($compile(template2)(scope));
            }
        },
        scope: {
            showIt: '='
        }
    }
});
```

In your view :

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a-directive show-it="showIt"> </a-directive>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. About your question: You can chack the "shoe-it" value in the link function of a-directive and append the connect content to the element:

   ```
     var content = scope.showIt ? '<inner-directive attr-directive="hello"></inner-directive>'
                                : '<inner-directive ></inner-directive>';
     element.append($compile(content)(scope));
   ```

If you do in the inner-directive as you did, you'll get an infinite loop cause the directive compiles itself so actually the link function calls itself.

1. Another problem you have is that both the inner-directive and the attr-directive try to change the template so you get the following error:

> Multiple directives [innerDirective, attrDirective] asking for
>   template on: <inner-directive attr-directive="hello">

So you should decide what the other directive should do. Here is an example: http://jsbin.com/OJACOqu/40/edit

Comment: The problem I have requires that I add the attribute directive to `inner-directive` (which is contained inside a template), so I can conditionally add it in `inner-directive` rather than in `a-directive`. The `attr-directive` should only be appending to the container - good catch! I'll update the example to make it more clear.

Comment: I've updated the example changing `attr-directive` to `value` directive to make things a bit more clear.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question... if you add directive from inside the link function you have to call $compile BUT when calling $compile of directive X from inside X's link function you get an infinit loop. So you should do it from outside X. In you case: add the value directive from the link function of a-directive and not from inner-directive (see my example)

Comment: Well in my real life code, I want the definition of `inner-directive` to contain `value`. So I want to compile `inner-directive` first, then  insert it into `a-directive`. Basically, I have a form directive (`a-directive`) and an input directive (`inner-directive`), and I want to dynamically add the `typeahead` attribute directive in the input directive based on an attribute on the form.